# Designing a builder as a compile-time state machine

Tags: api-design, finite-state-machine, builder-pattern, combinatorics

I'm working on a **text GUI** library which comes with builders for UI components (`Button`s, `Panel`s, etc). I have a base class for these builders which I'd like to redesign so that meaningless component states can't be represented with the builder. Right now the API looks like this (over simplified):

```
interface ComponentBuilder<T : Component, U : ComponentBuilder<T, U>> : Builder<T> {

    // aligns a component within a grid (only if it is not positioned directly)
    fun withAlignmentWithin(tileGrid: TileGrid, componentAlignment: ComponentAlignment): U

    // sets the position of a component directly (only if it is not aligned
    fun withPosition(x: Int, y: Int): U

    // sets the title of a component (only applicable if it is wrapped in a box)
    fun withTitle(title: String): U

    // defines the type of box we use for decorating the component with
    fun withBoxType(boxType: BoxType): U

    // wraps the component with a box (only if no decoration renderers are set)
    fun wrapWithBox(): U

    // wraps the component with a shadow (only if no decoration renderers are set)
    fun wrapWithShadow(): U

    // sets the given decoration renderers (only if we dont use box/shadow wrapping)
    fun withDecorationRenderers(vararg renderers: ComponentDecorationRenderer): U
}
```

and it can be used like this:

```
Components.panel()
        .withSize(10, 10)
        .withPosition(5, 5)
        .wrapWithBox()
        .wrapWithShadow()
        .withTitle("Test")
        .withBoxType(BoxType.SINGLE)
        .build()
```

and the result looks like this:

[image: example image here]

The problem is that the builder can get into a meaningless state like this:

```
Components.panel()
        .withTitle("Test") // meaningless, we have no box
        .withBoxType(BoxType.SINGLE) // same as above
        .build()
```

The problem is that the builder is supposed to be a state machine where some of the methods above can be an initial state, but when I move into one of those states it determines where I can go from there (for example I should only see *title/box type* if I moved into the *wrap with box* state first.

I tried to write a prototype for this but I realized that this leads into a combinatorial complexity boom:

```
interface ComponentBuilder<T : Component, U : ComponentBuilder<T, U>> : Builder<T> {

    fun withAlignmentWithin(tileGrid: TileGrid, componentAlignment: ComponentAlignment): AlignedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun withPosition(x: Int, y: Int): PositionedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun withDecorationRenderers(vararg renderers: ComponentDecorationRenderer): DecoratedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun wrapWithBox(wrapWithBox: Boolean = true): WrappedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun wrapWithShadow(wrapWithShadow: Boolean = true): WrappedComponentBuilder<T, U>
}

interface DecoratedComponentBuilder<T : Component, U : ComponentBuilder<T, U>> : Builder<T> {

    fun withAlignmentWithin(tileGrid: TileGrid, componentAlignment: ComponentAlignment): AlignedDecoratedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun withPosition(x: Int, y: Int): PositionedDecoratedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun withDecorationRenderers(vararg renderers: ComponentDecorationRenderer): DecoratedComponentBuilder<T, U>
}

interface AlignedDecoratedComponentBuilder<T : Component, U : ComponentBuilder<T, U>> : Builder<T> {

    fun withAlignmentWithin(tileGrid: TileGrid, componentAlignment: ComponentAlignment): AlignedDecoratedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun withDecorationRenderers(vararg renderers: ComponentDecorationRenderer): AlignedDecoratedComponentBuilder<T, U>
}

interface WrappedComponentBuilder<T : Component, U : ComponentBuilder<T, U>> : Builder<T> {

    fun withAlignmentWithin(tileGrid: TileGrid, componentAlignment: ComponentAlignment): WrappedAlignedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun withPosition(x: Int, y: Int): WrappedPositionedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun withTitle(title: String): WrappedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun withBoxType(boxType: BoxType): WrappedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun wrapWithShadow(wrapWithShadow: Boolean = true): WrappedComponentBuilder<T, U>
}

interface AlignedComponentBuilder<T : Component, U : ComponentBuilder<T, U>> : Builder<T> {

    fun withDecorationRenderers(vararg renderers: ComponentDecorationRenderer): U

    fun wrapWithBox(wrapWithBox: Boolean = true): WrappedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun wrapWithShadow(wrapWithShadow: Boolean = true): WrappedComponentBuilder<T, U>
}

interface PositionedComponentBuilder<T : Component, U : ComponentBuilder<T, U>> : Builder<T> {

    fun withDecorationRenderers(vararg renderers: ComponentDecorationRenderer): PositionedDecoratedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun wrapWithBox(wrapWithBox: Boolean = true): WrappedPositionedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun wrapWithShadow(wrapWithShadow: Boolean = true): WrappedPositionedComponentBuilder<T, U>
}

interface PositionedDecoratedComponentBuilder<T : Component, U : ComponentBuilder<T, U>> : Builder<T> {

    fun withDecorationRenderers(vararg renderers: ComponentDecorationRenderer): PositionedDecoratedComponentBuilder<T, U>

}

interface WrappedPositionedComponentBuilder<T : Component, U : ComponentBuilder<T, U>> : Builder<T> {

    fun withTitle(title: String): WrappedPositionedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun withBoxType(boxType: BoxType): WrappedPositionedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun wrapWithShadow(wrapWithShadow: Boolean = true): WrappedPositionedComponentBuilder<T, U>
}

interface WrappedAlignedComponentBuilder<T : Component, U : ComponentBuilder<T, U>> : Builder<T> {

    fun withAlignmentWithin(tileGrid: TileGrid, componentAlignment: ComponentAlignment): WrappedAlignedComponentBuilder<T, U>

    fun withTitle(title: String): U

    fun withBoxType(boxType: BoxType): U

    fun wrapWithShadow(wrapWithShadow: Boolean = true): U
}
```

My question is: *how can I write a builder API which retains its integrity but avoids the complexity boom above?* I might add some other options later so it needs to be scalable.

I'm working with Kotlin so any answer should be within the bounds of what's possible with Java and/or Kotlin.

Comment: The only sensible way I see is some kind of compile-time meta-programming. Macros, etc. if your language has them. Code generation if it doesn't.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't defining each the behaviors as separate interfaces and then combining them to create the allowable operations for each of these types?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I want to keep my API simple to use so I don't really want to introduce any additional complexity for the consumers of my API.

Comment: @JimmyJames can you elaborate a bit? I'm not sure I understand your question. The problem here is that the builder has internal state which I can't have in interfaces.

Comment: How much value is there in a) using the builder pattern and b) having the type-checker verify this state? It seems to me that it would be much easier to do either one without the other.

Comment: I'm using a builder for its simplicity and I'm trying to use a state machine to keep the consistency of the builder. I'm just trying to make my API better. If this doesn't work out I can still throw exceptions / log warnings instead.

Comment: You are getting ahead of me, I think.  You have a bunch of interfaces that define various combinations of the following seven methods: `withAlignmentWithin`, `withPosition`, `withDecorationRenderers`, `wrapWithShadow`, `wrapWithBox`, `withBoxType`, `withTitle`.  They return different types but let's set that aside of the moment.  Have you considered creating a one-method interface for each of these behaviors?

Comment: Not yet. How would those interfaces help in this case?

Comment: Not a fully baked idea but I'm wondering if you could use [intersection types](http://iteratrlearning.com/java/generics/2016/05/12/intersection-types-java-generics.html) to eliminate the need to create an interface for every combination.  The implementation might still be an issue but the nice thing about single method interfaces is that you can implement them with lambdas and/or method references.

Comment: Wow I tried that feature some years ago when I was curious whether if it was possible and I completely forgot since then. This might be a solution here!

Comment: Here's a more detailed link for that feature: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html.  A couple of side notes: don't forget to @ if you want a response and it's probably worth mentioning that your first solution is basically the GoF [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern.

Comment: If intersection types don't work out, would you be willing to provide the state machine? There are tricks you can play when building fluent APIs - for instance, you can overload `wrapWithBox()` into four methods, setting or not the box title and box type. Depending on the valid states and what must be called, you can also sometimes design side paths in your builder or do all the generic building first and then all the type-specific building.

Comment: `would you be willing to provide the state machine` <-- of course, all of this is open source!

Comment: So I checked and intersection types won't help here because where I implement more than 1 of these interfaces I can't restrict the generic type parameters because I don't know which method the user will call.

Comment: `abstract class AllBuilder<T : Component,
        A, P>
    : AlignmentBuilder<T, A> by DefaultAlignmentBuilder(),
        PositionBuilder<T, P> by DefaultPositionBuilder(),
        DecorationRendererBuilder<T, A> by DefaultDecorationRendererBuilder(),
        WrapperBuilder<T, A> by DefaultWrapperBuilder()
        where A : AlignmentBuilder<T, A>, A : DecorationRendererBuilder<T, A>,
              P : AlignmentBuilder<T, P>, P : DecorationRendererBuilder<T, P>`

Comment: This above is a compilation error because `A` is inconsistent with `P`.

Comment: BTW, writing code like this will, if nothing else, help you understand why *combinatorial explosion* is named "explosion".

Comment: @JörgWMittag I definitely agree!

Comment: And the state machine is ?  :)

Comment: Have you considered moving the dependent properties to objects that they depend on? For example `Components.panel().withBox(new box().withTitle("Test"))`. This would make it impossible to add a title to a component without a box.

Answer (score 3):

The only meaningful way I can think of "the builder with internal state" is something I've read long time ago in [this blog post](https://blog.crisp.se/2013/10/09/perlundholm/another-builder-pattern-for-java).

The idea is similar to proposals in comments which can achieved with additional internal interfaces.

Roughly speaking, you must introduce separate interface for each set-method what gives you ability to create a streamlined sequence of calls.

The obvious benefits are auto-complete and state safety of the final object, but the last point (safety) is up to you, because it depends on how you'd design your builder.

I don't think it will affect user experience except from external documentation point (interface cluttering).

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this without combinatorial explosion is to track whether the mandatory parameters have been provided through the builder's type parameters.
Such a builder then becomes `Builder<FirstPropertySet, SecondPropertySet, ..., LastPropertySet>`, where we take `Unit` as true and `Nothing` as false (although you could use anything here, these just make the most sense for Kotlin).

Each mandatory method returns the builder with the type parameter for the property in question set to `Unit`.
Optional methods simply leave the type parameters intact.

Furthermore, implementations of the builder should have a private constructor in order to prevent you from setting the type parameters yourself.
In this particular instance I've provided a fake constructor (`invoke` operator in companion), although any static method would suffice.

Finally, in order to gain type-safety, we introduce the type-safe build method as an extension function over the builder with all type parameters set to `Unit`, which simply calls the unsafe build method of the interface.

```
class Component(
    val a: String,
    val b: Int,
    val c: Boolean,
    val d: Double
)

interface ComponentBuilder<ASet, BSet, CSet> {
    // mandatory
    fun withA(a: String): ComponentBuilder<Unit, BSet, CSet>
    fun withB(b: Int): ComponentBuilder<ASet, Unit, CSet>
    fun withC(c: Boolean): ComponentBuilder<ASet, BSet, Unit>

    // optional
    fun withD(d: Double): ComponentBuilder<ASet, BSet, CSet>

    fun unsafeBuild(): Component
}

// Type-checked build method
fun ComponentBuilder<Unit, Unit, Unit>.build(): Component =
    unsafeBuild()

class ComponentBuilderImpl<ASet, BSet, CSet>
    private constructor() : ComponentBuilder<ASet, BSet, CSet> {

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(): ComponentBuilder<Nothing, Nothing, Nothing> =
            ComponentBuilderImpl()
    }

    private lateinit var a: String
    private var b: Int = 0
    private var c: Boolean = false
    private var d: Double = 0.7 // some default value

    override fun withA(a: String): ComponentBuilder<Unit, BSet, CSet> {
        this.a = a
        return this as ComponentBuilder<Unit, BSet, CSet>
    }

    override fun withB(b: Int): ComponentBuilder<ASet, Unit, CSet> {
        this.b = b
        return this as ComponentBuilder<ASet, Unit, CSet>
    }

    override fun withC(c: Boolean): ComponentBuilder<ASet, BSet, Unit> {
        this.c = c
        return this as ComponentBuilder<ASet, BSet, Unit>
    }

    override fun withD(d: Double): ComponentBuilder<ASet, BSet, CSet> {
        this.d = d
        return this
    }

    override fun unsafeBuild(): Component = Component(a, b, c, d)
}

fun main() {
    ComponentBuilderImpl().withB(3).build() // build() doesn't type-check
    ComponentBuilderImpl().withB(3).withA("x").withC(false).build() // type-checks
}
```

Comment: This is very interesting actually. I'm going to create a prototype for this soon!